# How to generate all ways to order a vector

Tags: c++

I have a programming exercise where you need to find all the ways in which you can arrange a vector.I searched and it was showing me just how to generate all subsets.Can someone explain how do you do this?
p.s in the exercise something like 1 2 3 4 and 4 3 2 1 count as two ways.

Comment: [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible way to print all permutations is to use [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print(const std::vector<int>& s)
{
    for (int i : s) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> s = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do {
        print(s);
    } while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
}
```

Comment: avoid nested loops. Use a function for printing.